# Clang 3.1 and user defined literals

Tags: c++, xcode4, c++11, clang

Clang 3.1 claims to support user defined literals. I can define this:

```
int operator"" _tryit(long double n) { return int(n); }
```

but when I try to use it I get an error:

```
int m = 5_tryit;
```

> Invalid suffix `'_tryit'` on integer constant

Comment: How about `int m = 5.0_tryit;`?

Comment: Apologies if I'm insulting your intelligence, but… that looks like the error I get when I compile in C++03 mode instead of C++11 mode, or when I use clang-3.0 instead of 3.1, not like any of the errors I get when I misuse a suffix in 3.1's C++11 mode. Are you sure you're using the right version and -std flag?

Answer (score 7):

`5` cannot be implicitly converted to a `long double` in your case. You need to change it to `5.0` to make it a long double or explicitly invoke the function yourself for the implicit conversion to work:

```
int m = 5.0_tryit;
```

OR

```
int n = operator"" _tryit(5);
```

(tested both with `clang version 3.1 (trunk) (llvm/trunk 155821)`)

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385297/overloading-rules-for-user-defined-literals-in-c0x) has a good explanation of the rules.

(Also, as abarnert mentions, make sure you are passing the `-std=c++11` flag to the compiler when compiling).

Comment: @John: I just tested `int m = 5.0_tryit;` with clang 3.1 and it worked for me.

Comment: Isn't there some versioning disconnect between what comes from Clang and what Apple ships? I.e., I don't think what Apple calls "Clang 3.1" is the same as what Clang calls "Clang 3.1". C.f. the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10603994/636019).

Comment: Apple's Xcode 4.3.2 version is not quite the same as you get with llvm.org's official llvm-3.1 version, and of course neither one is the same as the llvm/trunk 155821 listed in Jesse Good's answer above. But both the Xcode 4.3.2 version and the MacPorts clang-3.1 version seem to have the same behavior as what Jesse Good posted, so the differences apparently aren't relevant here.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Has anyone tested "5.0_tryit" with Xcode 4.4 (developer preview)'s version of what it claims is Clang 3.1?

Comment: @John: Did you pass the compiler flag (-std=c++11)?